# GridView contains duplicates while reopening the app second or third time

Tags: android, android-gridview

In my app, I set `GridView` with an adapter. In first time it loads correctly, but after closing my app and then if I reopen, then the content of `gridview` doubles. (i.e) each data in `gridview` is again added at end. I don't know the mistake.

MainActivity:

```
       girGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1_bir);
       ImageAdapter adapter;
       adapter=new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
       girGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
       girGridView.setColumnWidth(100);
```

ImageAdapter.class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

        GridViewConfig.addImageUrls();
    }

    public ImageAdapter(Context context1, String ff) {

        super();
        String g=ff;
        this.context = context1;

        GridViewConfig.addImageUrls(g);
    }

    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return GridViewConfig.getResim_list().size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        imageView=new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromURL(GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position)));
    }else{
        imageView=(ImageView)convertView;
    }

    return imageView;
}

private Drawable LoadImageFromURL(String url)
{
try
{
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
return d;
}catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
return null;
}
}
}
```

Comment: I had same problem, I solved with condition when I do "new image" I put condition only execute once, if(enter==true){ inicialize image; enter=false;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution, i just added created new Arraylist while adding image to gridview. Thats it. (i.e)I created arraylist to store the images in GridViewConfig class. Now i changed to the creation of arraylist just before adding the images.( Adding images to newly created array foe each and every time it loads)Hence i solved my problem. Thank You to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

In all adapter constructors you use  GridViewConfig.addImageUrls(g); what does  GridViewConfig? If it is singletone, than you just add new images every time when create new adapter.

Answer (score 0):

what is the GridViewConfig ?? 
possible answer, it is a class containing your data,
it is adding the image each time the adapter constructor is called, not replacing the current image.. you can say it like this:
initial data:
1. urlimage1

when you create the adapter, it added another image to the GridViewConfig so the data become:
1. urlimage1
2. urlimage1

so, to avoid this, you had to create a new GridViewConfig on the adapter constructor so it is empty on each adapter creation

well it's if GridViewConfig is a class